# c, macro with 2 arguments issue

Tags: c, macros

```
#define LED     3,3

#define GPIOHigh(port,pin)  (LPC_GPIO ## port->MASKED_ACCESS[(1<< pin)] = (1<< pin))
#define GPIOLow(port,pin)   (LPC_GPIO ## port->MASKED_ACCESS[(1<< pin)] = 0)

#define LED_ON()    GPIOHigh(LED)
#define LED_OFF()   GPIOLow(LED)
```

is not working, complaining about `GPIOHigh()` and `Low()` that needs 2 arguments.
Is there a magic trick out there?

Comment: A magic trick to achieve what? Do you intende `#define LED_ON(pin)  GPIOHigh(LED,pin)`? Or maybe `#define LED_ON  GPIOHigh(LED,42)`?

Comment: Yes, the magic trick is to pass two argument instead of the one that you are passing here

Comment: Common guys :) I try to make my code more elegant.

Comment: We can make the code more elegant if we can guess what it should perform

Comment: I try to use a simple #define LED 3,3 to describe LED

Comment: Of course, I could use #define LED_ON GPIOHigh(3,3) but it's 1/2 ugly

Comment: For such a short piece, it won't really matter if you write it out a bit more than trying to use a macro as two arguments.

Comment: Well, if anyone has a crystal ball.. please touch a bit, I'm sure it can be done on gcc

Answer (score 1):

"LED" 3,3 is interpreted as a single argument. So it is complaining that it is missing another argument. Macro substitutions are not always a literal substitution of one into another.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your code:

```
    #define TOKEN_EXPAND(a, b) a b
    #define LED_OFF()          TOKEN_EXPAND(GPIOLow, (LED))
```

As a test, the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define LED                3,3
#define GPIOLow(port,pin)  (LPC_GPIO ## port->MASKED_ACCESS[(1 << pin)] = 0)
#define TOKEN_EXPAND(a, b) a b
#define LED_OFF()          TOKEN_EXPAND(GPIOLow, (LED))

struct {
   int MASKED_ACCESS[32];
} test, *LPC_GPIO3 = &test;

int main(void) {
   test.MASKED_ACCESS[8] = 1234;
   printf("%d\n", test.MASKED_ACCESS[8]);
   LED_OFF();
   printf("%d\n", test.MASKED_ACCESS[8]);
   return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
1234
0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to circumvent is a safety feature of macro expansion.

```
#define GPIOHigh(pair)  do { int a[]=pair; int port=a[0], pin=a[1]; ...;  } while (0)
#define LED  {3,3}
#define LED_ON   GPIOHigh(LED)
```

Of course that does not allow you to use `##` with the `port`any more ...